# Yandex map не дружит с Grid

Tags: css, css3, yandex-maps-api, css-grid

При добавлении блоку свойства `display: grid`, Яндекс карта внутри этого блока перестает динамически подстраиваться под размер окна браузера. Меняет свой размер только при обновлении страницы. Обернуть карту в ещё один блок и присвоить ему `display: block` не помогает.

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

у меня получилось при помощи блока с абсолютным позиционированием внутри грида. Вот пример:

```css
#container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}

#subcontainer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Вот полноценный пример: https://jsfiddle.net/x2r009kq/14/

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
    zoom: 9
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
}

#subcontainer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="subcontainer">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Решил проблему добавив google maps вместо yandex, у них нет таких проблем с Grid, но на будущее буду знать как можно решить проблему с yandex. Спасибо за совет!

Comment: А в чём смысл CSS Grid, если использовать абсолютное позиционирование? Данный пример работает независимо от того, если ли у блока `#container` свойство `display: grid`. Да и вообще использовать абсолютное позиционирование в данной ситуации видится мне бессмысленным. Вы можете удалить все стили с `#subcontainer` и данный код всё равно будет работать.